# Why does Next.js prefix the app.js with an underscore?

Tags: next.js

When I create a Next.js project with the `npx create-next-app` command than there is an `_app.js` file under the `pages` folder. In which case do I need to prefix a file with an underscore in a Next.js project?

Comment: It's an file that you can custom your initialize page and the name is decided by official `next.js` team. For more introduction, you can reference the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [Custom `App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Next.js uses the `App` component to initialize pages.

> To override the default `App`, create the file `./pages/_app.js`

---

- [Custom `Document`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

A custom `Document` is commonly used to augment your application's `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

> To override the default `Document`, create the file
> `./pages/_document.js`

Answer (score 4):

You're only gonna need that prefix in the default nextjs pages like _app.js, the _document.js, etc. you can look it up in the [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), I think the prefix is used to avoid routes like "/app" or "/document", and let them free in case you need use them for your project.